# What is the difference between -さん and -さま?

Tags: suffixes

Recently I watched the film "The Wind Rises" by Studio Ghibli in Japanese with English subtitles. I heard one of the children referring to an elder as [name]-さま. I was wondering, what is the difference between -さん and -さま?

Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sama (様【さま】) is a markedly more respectful version of san. It is used mainly to refer to people much higher in rank than oneself, toward one's guests or customers (such as a sports venue announcer addressing members of the audience), and sometimes toward people one greatly admires and can be used for either gender.

See the Wikipedia article [Japanese honorifics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_honorifics)